# Hidden Timecapsule Features

Tags: time-capsule

I can remember the old version of the Airport Configuration Utility. Back then it was possible to display graphs for WiFi devices and such. So the timecapsule pretty sure can do more than there is in the frontend of the new utility.

Is there any software that provides those hidden functionalities to the hands of a user?

Comment: This is not helpful to you if you run Mountain Lion, but just FYI, I had a separate install of Airport Utility 5.6 before I upgraded to Mountain Lion and it still has the functionality you mentioned (the "Advanced" tab). It can also still be downloaded (http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1482) but unfortunately refuses to install on Mountain Lion.

Comment: @root Incidentally, you can install Airport Utility 5.6 on ML, it just involves extracting the application out of the dmg. There are several Apple Support Community threads about it, like [this one](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4255936?start=0&tstart=0)

Comment: Or look here: http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/57453/9058