# Restart airport router via command line

Tags: network, airport

Is there any way to restart an apple router via the commandline?

Problem: My airport express starts to "give out" every day or so. I usually have to unplug it for a couple of seconds and then plug it back in. By "give out" I mean it isn't connected to the network and is flashing a yellow light. So, I'm looking for an automatic way to restart the express. I've looked into `snmp` and it doesn't seem like there's a way to send commands, it's only for stats it seems.

To clarify:

I do not care using Command line, or any other means of remotely resetting the router.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is possible, check out this link:

https://github.com/samuelthomas2774/airport/wiki/SSH

I stumbled upon this as I was trying to figure out how to remotely reboot the Airport Extreme while having “setup over WAN” disabled, but still having VPN access to a server in the local network.

Apparently using the [node-acp](https://github.com/samuelthomas2774/airport/wiki/node-acp) utility it is as simple as running

```
acp --host airport-extreme.local --password password reboot
```

Comment: Might be worth mentioning that https://github.com/samuelthomas2774/airport/wiki/node-acp needs to be installed for this to work.

Answer (score 1):

[It's not possible to access the Airport Express from the command line](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/66721/how-do-i-activate-snmp-on-airport-base-stations#comment78609_66724).

If you want to dig into `SNMP` and are comfortable with `Java`, you can look at the code for the latest version of the [Linux version of Airport Utility](https://code.launchpad.net/~ubuntu-branches/ubuntu/saucy/airport-utils/saucy-proposed) on Ubuntu Launchpad.

Comment: I wish I was comfortable with Java, but I'm not at this moment. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If this is the current AppleTV-styled revision, it should most certainly be under warranty, and the best solution is probably replacing it, not rebooting it.

If it's the old 802.11g brick-style model, you'll want to try an earlier firmware unless you absolutely cannot live without multi-speaker AirPlay. The last firmware update for the 802.11g models has an issue with some (generally earlier) units and will crash after some time. Rolling back to [firmware 6.1.1](http://support.apple.com/kb/DL519) resolves the issue.