# How to run old AirPort Utils 5.x on MacOS X maverics?

Tags: airport

How to run old  AirPort Utils 5.x on MacOS X maverics ? Because the new one is really ugly.

Comment: Additionally, the new one can't control older Airport devices! I just discovered that 5.6 won't run, but 6 won't work with my Airport. Did I just lock myself out of my device by upgrading?

Comment: https://plus.google.com/app/basic/stream/z13uybnpitn3hzsin04cjjbojnjqjrdxo0w Claims to have a workaround for this but I haven't tried it myself yet.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I still use the older Airport Utility 5.5.3 if I install the 6.0 version of Airport Utility?](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/38855/can-i-still-use-the-older-airport-utility-5-5-3-if-i-install-the-6-0-version-of)

Comment: @grgarside The linked question is more broad and not restricted to Mavericks.

Answer (score 6):

There is a workaround detailed here: http://coreyjmahler.com/2013/10/24/airport-utility-5-6-1-on-os-x-10-9-mavericks/.

Answer (score 2):

I just got off the phone with Apple support and the official answer is that you can't run AirPort Utility 5.x on Mavericks or even on Mountain Lion.

[image]

Now I *did* have it successfully running in Mountain Lion, so I know that it is possible in that scenario, but when I tried to use Terminal to force it to run under Mavericks, I got this error:

[image]

Maybe there's a workaround, but so far, I haven't gotten anything to work. Which means that I have to boot up my old eMac to control my Airport Express, because Airport Utility version 6 isn't compatible with my Airport Express, but Airport Utility 5.6 isn't compatible with Mavericks or Mountain Lion.

Answer (score 2):

Airport Utility 5.6 is using library calls which are no longer available in the libraries provided with Mavericks (see [this discussion](http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?p=17593014) for details). I finally used Parallels to run Mountain Lion in a VM and copied Airport Utility 5.6 into that VM. Works like a charm...