# See all active clients with Airport Extreme/Express

Tags: airport

How can I see all (active) clients on my Airport Extreme. I can’t find such option in the current Airport Utility.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your need is a list of the wireless clients you can see them in the current (6.3.x) Airport Utility; hold down ALT and double-click the Extreme.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by [installing an older version of AirPort Utility](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/38855/can-i-still-use-the-older-airport-utility-5-5-3-if-i-install-the-6-0-version-of). Alternatively, you can use 3rd-party software…

### [iNet](http://www.inetapp.de)

iNet will scan your network for all connected devices and show you a list of devices with their hostnames and IP addresses. It also has a **dedicated mode for AirPort routers** showing devices connected and relevant information about each one.

[image]