# Can't see A1084 AirPort Express behind A1354 AirPort Extreme

Tags: network, wifi, airport

Can anyone please make any suggestions...? (Preferably, step by step instructions to resolve this issue).

I am using AirPort Utility 6.3.2 on a MacBook Pro running MacOS X 10.9.1 Mavericks.  AirPort Utility suddenly can't see my two A1084 AirPort Express base stations behind my A1354 AirPort Extreme (which is running Firmware version 7.6.4).  The Extreme is behind a CenturyLink Actiontec C1000A DSL modem, which is connected to the Internet.

If I use AirPort Utility set the Extreme to "DHCP and NAT," the utility shows that the Extreme has "Double NAT."

[image: AirPort Extreme set for "DHCP & NAT"]

If I set the Extreme to "Bridge Mode," that issue resolves.

[image: AirPort Extreme set for "Bridge Mode"]

But, in neither case can I see the AirPort Express base stations.

There is a control to disable NAT in the Actiontec C1000A DSL modem's admin panel, but an attempt to make that change doesn't "take" when I click on "Apply").

[image: Actiontec C1000A control panel for NAT]

Because the AirPort Express units are old, only the old AirPort Utility (v5.x) can be used to configure them - but, that old version does not run under Mavericks.

[image: AirPort Utility 5.6 doesn't run under Mavericks]

Comment: See this question regarding [AirPort Utility 5.6 on Mavericks](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/38855/can-i-still-use-the-older-airport-utility-5-5-3-if-i-install-the-6-0-version-of).

Answer (score 2):

I cannot comment your post, but at least I have a suggestion: Download a copy of Airport Utility 5.6 working with Mavericks [here](http://coreyjmahler.com/2013/10/24/airport-utility-5-6-1-on-os-x-10-9-mavericks/).

Edit: it seems to me your network is working as always (at least before you began fiddling...:-)), but the thing is you updated Airport Utility to the newest version and therefore cannot see the Expresses? This is a "feature" of the newest Airport Utility.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  Unfortunately v5.6 does not work under Mavericks.  Is there a Windows version equivalent to v5.6 that I can install on my wife's computer, and try from there?

Comment: The version in the supplied link works under Mavericks, I used it myself - just follow the instructions.

Comment: AWESOME!!! It works like a champ.  Thank you.  Now, I have a configured AirPort Extreme, and the 5.6 utility shows two unconfigured AirPort Express base stations.  I want to connect those to the Extreme.  The first thing that happens is that they ask me to switch networks, which loses visibility to the Extreme.  Can you direct me to step-by-step instructions to join the Expresses to the Extreme?  (Ideally, so they extend the range of the Extreme) Thanks.

Comment: I am no expert on this, but I believe you run airport utility while connected to the extreme. If the expresses dont show up you have to press the reset button on them. Pretty sure they will connect to the network you were originally on (the extreme) - the macbook will switch back and forth a couple of times, but it'll all end good if you let it do its job. Just select "extend network" instead of join/create when you have the option. Btw unless you really have to extend the coverage of the extreme it'll be better to just have them joining, as extending will slow your whole network down.

Comment: Got it - And it worked.  Thanks so much.  After reading your comment, I decided to "join existing network" instead of extending.  Hope I can return the favor someday!

Comment: You're welcome, glad I could help! I take it you use the expresses for streaming audio? Then joining is probably best, if signal is strong enough. You can check signal strength in spotlight (magnifying glass) -> search for wireless diagnostics -> window menu -> utilities -> Performance. Maybe compare when expresses join and extend. The other half of the equation is the transfer rate ("Tx Rate"). I'm not sure it reflects the true rate though, but maybe it'll give you an idea.