# Upgrade system frameworks without upgrading OS

Tags: macos, upgrade

I am currently running macOS 10.10.2, but would like to be able to run the latest Ableton Live 10 which is built on macOS 10.11.  When I directly run the executable I get errors referencing symbols not found in:

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/AudioToolbox.framework/Versions/A/AudioToolbox.
```

Of course this issue would be resolved by upgrading to 10.11, but that is something that I really do not want to do for a number of reasons, so I am wondering if I can:

1. Extract the relevant Framework files from a El Capitan InstallESD.dmg, and
2. Overwrite the existing framework files with the new ones.

How much am I missing, or would this work?

Thanks

Edit:  I want to know if this is possibile, not if it is a good idea.

Comment: Have you contacted the developer of this application and asked them how to do this on 10.10.2?

Comment: @fsb No, but I doubt they would.

Comment: Step 2 will fail due to SIP. Whether it works at all depends on the dependencies between AudioToolbox and all other frameworks.

Comment: Related https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/38855/can-i-still-use-the-older-airport-utility-5-5-3-if-i-install-the-6-0-version-of

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically no
 Upgrading system components is basically upgrading the OS.

Look at this in a micro fashion.

You need to upgrade a library because its API changed. OK that library depends itself on a new API so that needs to be upgraded and repeat until when?

Answer (score 1):

Ableton Live 10 isn't even released yet.

- https://www.ableton.com/en/blog/live-10-coming-february-6

You should also check the system requirements.

- https://help.ableton.com/hc/en-us/articles/115001663530-Live-10-Minimum-System-Requirements

> OS X 10.11.6 or later

So I think the answer to your question is don't modify system frameworks (sounds like a recipe for dependency hell) and either upgrade to macOS 10.11 or stick to using Ableton Live 9.

Comment: Ableton Live 10 has a public beta. That is what I am running.

Comment: This answer doesn't really give me what I want, but thank you for the advice.

Comment: Ableton isn't an open source project where you can compile it to run on whatever you want it to run on if you know how. Even if you could make something like this work, you'll probably run into more issues when you want to update.

According to both https://support.apple.com/en-au/HT201222 & https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OS_X_Yosemite the last security update for OS X 10.10 was July 19, 2017. Given the latest round of CVE's that affected Intel processors I'm unsure why you would choose to remain on that version of OS X.